# Unknown Identifier Error only on Modelsim?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following HDL description which compiles successfully in Quartus but gives me an error in Modelsim.

I tried to do the code using only `std_logic_vector` but it did not work out.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity upcounter is
port(
S,NF : in  std_logic_unsigned (2 downto 0);
O : out  std_logic_unsigned (2 downto 0));

end upcounter;


architecture struct of upcounter is
begin 

if (S < NF) then
countup: while (S < NF) loop
S <= S + '1';
end loop countup;
else 

countdown: while (S > NF) loop
 S <= S - '1';
 end loop countdown;
 end if;


  O <= S;

 end struct;
```

Comment: Could you show the complete error message?

Comment: You don't provide [a specific error nor expected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are apparent errors. You can't assign mode in port S. Loops are sequential statements while those appear in the architecture statement part where only concurrent statements are allowed. With an intermediary signal or a variable in a process the behavior isn't synthesis eligible. The loop statements would be gated oscillators depending on unknown implementation delay to gate properly where counters should be sequential logic (clocked) and aren't necessary. O would have the value of NF.

Comment: ** Error: C:/Users/islam/Desktop/University (AUK)/Fall 2018/CPEG 210 L/final project/upcounter.vhd(10): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic_unsigned". This is the error message.

Comment: The two instances of `std_logic_unsigned` should be just `unsigned`. There are still other issues with your code.